# GWT - How can I see the HTML code?

Tags: html, gwt

Im using netbeans and the framework GWT. Due to the GWT structure, on my browser i can't see the html code with the simple "View Source". How can I see this? Im using Google Chrome.
Bye

Answer (score 6, accepted):

View Source only shows you the HTML page that was downloaded (i.e., not much). Try using Chrome's [Developer Tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools) to see the DOM structure after GWT's loaded. You can also use it to see network traffic from the page, and see JS errors if there are any.

Comment: I tried that Inspect element, but i can't see the <div> structure. I see only javascript code...

Comment: Click on the "Elements" tab at the top of the developer tools panel.  It's in the same line of tabs with "Resources," "scripts," "Timeline," etc.

Comment: yeah i see!!! Now it works. Just dont understand why it show to me 2 HTML and 2 BODY tag for that page. But it works!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with exactly the same situation. I use the Firefox extension [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/): on the "View Source" menu there is an option "View Generated Source".

[image]

Comment: uhm looks nice! There is somethings like Web Developer for google chrome?